# Yii2 SluggableBehavior

Tags: php, yii2, slug

Как запретить `Yii2` генерить новый `slug` при обновлении записи, если не изменен `title` или сам `slug` ? Сам код генерации сейчас выглядит так:

```
[
    'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
    'ensureUnique' => true,
    'value' => function( $event )
    {
        if( $event->sender->slug )
        {
            $slug = $event->sender->slug;
        }
        else
        {
            $slug = Inflector::slug( $event->sender->title );
        }
        return $slug . '-test';
    },
]
```

Проблема в том что `Yii2` генерит slug каждый раз по новой. К примеру

Добавление

> nazvanie-test

Первое обновление

> nazvanie-test-test

Второе обновление

> nazvanie-test-test-test

и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Под ваше условие код ниже. Так же обратите внимание, что существует свойство [SluggableBehavior::immutable](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior.html#$immutable-detail), но оно не подходит под условие.

```
[
    'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
    'ensureUnique' => true,
    'value' => function( $event )
    {
        if( $event->sender->isAttributeChanged('title') || $event->sender->isAttributeChanged('title'))
        {
            return Inflector::slug( $event->sender->title ) . '-test';
        }

        return $event->sender->slug;
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

У себя сделал так:

При создании записи - генерируем слаг.

При обновлении - ничего не делать со слагом.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'title',//поле с которого генерируем слаг
            'slugAttribute' => 'surname',//поле которое используется как слаг
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'surname',//заполнять при создании
                //ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE => 'surname'//заполнять при обновлении - если надо
            ],
        ]
    ];
}
```